# TensorFlow - OCR on image file

Tags: tensorflow, ocr

I am beginner to tensorflow and deep learning. Currently, i am planning using TensorFlow to do OCR that can extract the information from image file. The information in the image files can be printed text or handwritting text. In my server, i have million of this image file.

Below is my sample image file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoHwF.jpg)

And i have study some article about OCR that made by Tensorflow. Below is article link:

https://github.com/githubharald/SimpleHTR/tree/master

https://github.com/lamhoangtung/LineHTR

https://towardsdatascience.com/faq-build-a-handwritten-text-recognition-system-using-tensorflow-27648fb18519

My question is before i start my work, should i create my own dataset that is image file available in my server? or i should use back MNIST dataset or dataset at online?

if i create my own dataset, do i need to crop it, then only used for train model?

Comment: Recognizing printed text is very different from handwriting. The best solution is most probably a combination of different techniques.

Comment: Do you mean for printed text have to use tesseract, for handwriting will use Tensorflow?

Comment: It could be a good start. Or maybe 2 different models. For example OpenVINO has 2 different pretrained models: https://github.com/opencv/open_model_zoo/blob/master/models/intel/index.md#text-recognition

Comment: what is mean tight align crop in the article?

Comment: do i need to pay for it if we use this 2 model?